# Where could I find the ifcfg-eth0 file?

Tags: networking, rhel, configuration, ethernet

I am using RHEL6, but I could not find the Ethernet interface configuration file `ifcfg-eth0` under `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts`. Issuing `ifconfig -a` shows that `eth0` does exist. Could it be that the configuration file is hidden or saved in some other directory? If not, could I create such a file in the default directory(i.e., `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts`) so that it would serve as the default configuration file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could find an example in `/usr/share/doc*/initscript*`, can't remember the exact name, but I'll provide a comprehensive example here:

All fields are fairly easy to understand

```
DEVICE=eth0 
BOOTPROTO=none 
ONBOOT=yes 
NETWORK=10.0.1.0 
NETMASK=255.255.255.0 
IPADDR=10.0.1.27
```

[Docs here](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-networkscripts-interfaces.html)

Comment: Sorry, but do you mean that I can create that `ifcfg-eth0` file myself? Do you know why the default file is missing? Thank you.

Comment: @xczzhh just create one, no idea why it's missing

Comment: Agreeing that you could just create the file.  On two CentOS 6 machines I checked (which should be similar enough to RHEL6 where it counts), both already have `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`, just like previous RHEL5/CentOS5.

Answer (score 0):

Corresponding directory to /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts in Ubuntu
is /usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/
The details of the configuration procedures can be seen in the procedure configure_networking() script inside /usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/functions

Answer (score -4):

I haven't managed a RHEL6 machine before, but usually on Linux, network interfaces are configured in the `interfaces` file. I'm speaking from experience on Debian and Ubuntu boxes, where `man interfaces` explains the syntax and mentions a default file location of `/etc/network/interfaces`. Is this the same as on Red Hat?

Comment: The configuration file of network interfaces for redhat linux is not the same as that for Ubuntu, and there is no such a directory as `/etc/network/interfaces` in RHEL6. Thank you anyways :)

Comment: The `/etc/network/interfaces` file is used by `ifupdown`, which is specific to Debian and derivatives of Debian.